# Finding the equation of the locus

Tags: geometry

Find the equation of a locus that a point moves so that it is always equidistant from(-5,5) and (-2,2).

Comment: Were you able to locate any such points, equidistant from $(-5,5)$ and $(-2,2)$?  Have you studied plane geometry to know what sort of "curve" this motion traces?  In general it improves a question to add what context you already know, thereby saving repetition of material and helping your Readers focus on replies that are useful to you.

Answer (score 2):

Let $P=(x,y)$. Essentially, you want an algebraic expression relating $x$ and $y$. Since the distance from $P$ to $(-5,5)$ and $(-2,2)$ are equal, using the distance formula gives
$$\sqrt{(x+5)^2+(y-5)^2}=\sqrt{(x+2)^2+(y-2)^2}$$
This equation does indeed relate the two variables. Can you proceed and simplify?

Answer (score 0):

The locus that a point moves so that it is always equidistant from two points would be the perpendicular bisector of the line segment connecting the two points.

The point right at the middle would be $(-3.5,3.5)$.

The slope of the line was is -1. Hence our locus will take gradient 1.

$$(y-3.5)=x+3.5$$
$$y=x+7$$